# how to make my wpf window over a uwp fullscreen window

Tags: wpf, uwp, fullscreen, topmost

I have a wpf subtransparent window and I want it on the topmost. I set it's topmost  property as true. For most cases, it can come at the most top. However, when there is a uwp app run in full screen mode, my window cannot come over. How should I do?

Comment: It's by design, depending on the definition of full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Back in Windows 8 I had a similar problem. I wanted an app to be visible top most over Windows 8 FullScreen app.

Any regular app is not visible over Windows 8 Apps or the Windows 8 Start-Screen, even if it is TopMost.

If I remember correctly, there are certain limitations: an app has to be signed and must run from inside the system32 folder! Than the app is still visible, even if a Windows 8 App is active. - Example of this is the Task-Manager.

In Windows 8 I was able to develop a test application that was still visible over Start-Screen and Metro-Apps. I assume in Windows 10 it is just the same thing.